Why pwndbg interprets the input as a command but not as input to the program?
I'm debugging a program which has anti-debug techniques. One was to detect ptrace which pwndbg evaded easily but now the when the program expects an input pwndbg interprets it as its own command rather to pass input to the program. Am I missing something??
Example:
Waiting to initialize.
Started.
Enter a prompt: e
Ambiguous command "e": eb, echo, ed, edit, egrep, elfsections, emulate, en, enable, end, entry, env, environ, envp, eq...

